# DLL Import (import dynamic dll library on windows)

Tags: c++, erlang

I need to make Erlang <- C++ Bridge

I'm making win32 dynamic library :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

#ifdef _MANAGED
    #pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

#define DLLExport   __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    DLLExport int RunOPC(int);
    DLLExport void Save();
}
```

And want to import and use this functions from Erlang. How to import this functions and use them on Erlang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement erlang linkedin driver or erlang port.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html

Answer (score 1):

I am yet to use it but you could try http://thrift.apache.org